# center the whole of a canvas block superimposed on an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page without scrolling (with position: fixed on the body) and by placing an image and block canvas inside div I can't center it inside the browser screen. Align -... do not work. I've tried padding and margin, but it never gets accurate and responsive.
Here there is the my personal case, simplifyed

```
   [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/andrea97/xzb9y7he/2/#&togetherjs=C9zV7zNl2L
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a class `center`. Styling for this class:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard. CSS `margin: auto` does it for you.
Have a look at the code example below.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

div > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">  
      </div>

      <style> div{
          top: 40%;
        left: 45%;
        right:50%;
        position:absolute;
        }</style>
    
</body>
</html>


try this this may help you


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/avjbb.png
```